# Generate ordered passwords for brute forcing in C

Tags: c

I don't know how to explain my need using only words, so let's see an example and check for details.

I want to generate passwords with length of 5 Letters only Upper/Lower case inside my program like this:

```
aaaaa
aaaab
aaaac
.....
AAAAA
AAAAB
.....
bbbba
bbbbb
.....
```

Try all combination begining from '`aaaa`' until '`ZZZZZ`'.

Mixed upper/lower case is allowed and required for my use.

I got this code, but it don't supporte Upper case (I want mixed Lower and Upper case).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int isFinish(char *str){
    return '\0'== str[strspn(str, "z")];
}

void inc_str(char *str){
    int index, carry;
    for(index = strlen(str)-1;index>=0;--index){
        if(str[index] == 'z'){
            carry = 1;
            str[index] = 'a';
        } else {
            carry = 0;
            str[index] += 1;
        }
        if(carry == 0)break;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    char *str;

    n=7;//length
    str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1));
    //initialize
    memset(str, 'a', n);//"aa..aa"
    str[n]='\0';

    while(1){
        printf("%s\n", str);
        if(isFinish(str))
            break;
        inc_str(str);
    }
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10161603/11622790

Comment: All you need to do is count. But instead of using base 10, use base 52.

Comment: @user3386109 Can you develop your answer a little please ? Thank you again

Comment: Solutions in C++ probably won't work in C, and solutions in C are probably not appropriate (idiomatic) for C++.  Choose one or the other language, not both.  Do you need to be able to handle 6 character passwords too — or just 4 character ones — or is it strictly sufficient to code for length 5?  You _could_ (but probably shouldn't) simply code nested loops.  Alternatively, you can use recursion of some sort.  But you've not shown the barest attempt to solve the problem — you should show your best effort and describe the issues with it.  We won't write your homework for you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just found a code that will do it ... but left only one problem, mixe Upper and Lower case. The length must be specified like the updated code.

Comment: Modify inc_str to continue to 'A' once it reaches 'z', then stop at 'Z'.

Comment: Note: From a C++ standpoint, this code is "horrible", one of the problems Jonathan Leffler was warning about.

Comment: Use a constant literal string `const char alphabet[] = "abcdef"` ... `"xyzABC"` ... `"XYZ";` then some `alphabet[i]` -or define a `nextletter(char c)` function

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Any small help for that please ? I need to detect first if upper case or ?

Comment: I'm not keen on that code, though I suppose it works.  Extending it to handle upper-case as well as lower-case is not very difficult.  You can start with `aaaaa` and when you get to increment past a `z`, use `A`, then recycle back to `a` when you reach `Z`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Any code to point if possible ? I can't find no where example using alphabet list.

Comment: No. You are expecting us to do your homework. But if we did, you are not learning anything.

Comment: It already tests for 'z'. Replace the "then" clause of that with no carry and set digit to 'A'. Add a new test for 'Z' that does what the current 'z' does.

Comment: Also, put only one tag: `c` or `c++`. These languages are so different that having both tags make no sense

Comment: Note that you'll generate 52^5 (380,204,032) strings.  That's quite boring.  The question you pulled the code from also has an answer using recursion.  That's probably a neater solution to use.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson You are the only one guy given the best answer here without taking him self for a super developer and it's you, problem solved, thank you. If you create a comment I can validate your answer.

Comment: Thanks, but this is likely not a long-term post: it's not broadly useful. Glad to be of help though (and feel free to post your solution as an answer yourself; that's perfectly acceptable).

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Thank's again

Answer (score 2):

I modified this code with the help of @L. Scott Johnson to supprt UPPER/LOWER case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int isFinish(char *str){
    return '\0'== str[strspn(str, "Z")];
}

void inc_str(char *str){
    int index, carry;
    for(index = strlen(str)-1;index>=0;--index){
        if(str[index] == 'Z'){
            carry = 1;
            str[index] = 'a';
        } else if(str[index] == 'z'){
            carry = 0;
            str[index] = 'A';
        } else {
            carry = 0;
            str[index] += 1;
        }
        if(carry == 0)break;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    char *str;

    n=7;//length
    str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1));
    //initialize
    memset(str, 'a', n);//"aa..aa"
    str[n]='\0';

    while(1){
        printf("%s\n", str);
        if(isFinish(str))
            break;
        inc_str(str);
    }
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: under 'z', set `carry = 0`

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Excellent ! I was looking for a solution to that problem just right now :D You solved it many thank's again :)